# Big numbers with fraction support

Tags: c#, numeric

I need a c# number something that can handle very large numbers but also fraction support, I looked at System.Numerics.BigInteger coming in .NET 4.0 but I can't get it to work with fractions.

```
something i = 2;
something j = 5;
something k = i/j; //should be 0.4
```

when i tried

```
 BigInteger i = 2;
 BigInteger j = 5;
 double d = (double)(i/j); //d is 0.0
```

Does anybody know such a library?

Comment: You're only casting the integer division result ( which is already an integer ) as a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once used this library:
[W3b.Sine](http://sine.codeplex.com/Wikipage). It's:

> An arbitrary-precision decimal number
>   library developed in C#.

You could also try http://www.fractal-landscapes.co.uk/bigint.html. However, I have no experience using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this source no longer exists.

Answer (score 10):

[F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) contains a numeric type `BigRational`. It is implemented in F# and designed for F#, but the type should be perfectly usable from C# as well (including overloaded operators and stuff like that). PowerPack is an additional library with extra F# features, so it isn't a part of the .NET framework, but it's a supported product from Microsoft.

The `BigRational` type supports all basic operators (`+, /, -, *, >, <, >=, <=, ==, !=`) and I believe that it automatically keeps a normal form of the number. If you represented the number as two `BigInteger` values, you'd have to implement comparison such that *1/2* equals *2/4*.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Mathematics/Arbitrary_Precision_Arithmetic/Arbitrary_Precision_Rationals.aspx

Although maybe you just want to do this: `double d = ((double)i) / ((double)j);`

Answer (score 1):

Consider if the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) class is big enough:

> The Decimal value type represents
>   decimal numbers ranging from positive
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335
>   to negative
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.
>   The Decimal value type is appropriate
>   for financial calculations requiring
>   large numbers of significant integral
>   and fractional digits and no round-off
>   errors.

If you want to go really big, then look for a "bignum" library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (and google for [bindings](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/)).

Answer (score 0):

This should give a good approximation converting a rational number of two BigIntegers to  a double:

```
struct BigRational
{
    BigInteger numerator;
    BigInteger denominator;

    public double ToDouble()
    {
        BigInteger quotient;
        BigInteger remainder;

        quotient = BigInteger.DivRem(numerator, denominator, out remainder);

        return (double)quotient + (double)remainder / (double)denominator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad, now just extend it to support all the other operations.

Comment: Yes come on what are you waiting for? Your free sample is too brief ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An experimental [BigRational in BCL Codeplex](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational) based on BigInteger

Answer (score -1):

BigInteger supports just what it says on the tin - integral numbers, which fractions are not.

The `double` datatype supports binary floating-point numbers from ±5.0 × 10<sup>−324</sup> to ±1.7 × 10<sup>308</sup>, and `decimal` support decimal floating-point numbers from ±1.0 × 10<sup>−28</sup> to ±7.9 × 10<sup>28</sup>.  Gabe's answer mentions classes you can use to model fractions, but stick with the primitive datatypes if the ranges are sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

What is the range for your 'very large numbers'?

System.Double.MaxValue = **1.7976931348623157E+308**, which seems to be a pretty large number for me, though ([MSDN Double.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx))

Comment: But dynamic range is very wide for Doubles but precision is not that high - only 15-17 significant figures. Which is a real problem as rounding errors can and do creep in to calculations. Decimal lacks the dynamic range. Ideally there needs to be a SuperType which has 128bits, much higher and the same or greater exponent range as double.

Answer (score -2):

Would i/j even mean anything? They're instances of a class, you need to be using BigInteger.Divide(i, j)

Though it's designed to work with integers, so I should imagine it'll throw away any remainder. Which, if it does support straight division without the function call, is why you're getting 0.

Comment: BigInteger defines an overload for the division operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_division(v=VS.100).aspx) so `i/j` is the same as `BigInteger.Divide(i, j)`