# C# - Greater decimal accuracy than Decimal type

Tags: c#, decimal, precision

Is it possible to get more decimal precision than the `decimal` type in C#? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx), the `decimal` type can store up to 29 significant digits, however I am wondering if it possible to store more than that and how to go about doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big numbers with fraction support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533960/big-numbers-with-fraction-support) - Has useful links in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - you can come up with your own data type (or use an existing third party library - the J++ runtime has an implementation of BigDecimal usable from C#).

What do you need that for? It is VERY unusual to need more than 29 significant digits ;)

Comment: This question is more theoretical then practical. Recently I was trying to write a program to write Pi to a certain number of decimal places and I realized that I could only store up to 29 decimal places. Thus this question was born.

Comment: Yeah. Mathematical playing is pretty much the only real use ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scaled [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_members.aspx) if you're using 4.0.  That will make arithmetic easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BigRational` class in [BCL](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782). However It's still in beta version ...