# C# high precision calculations

Tags: c#, .net, sqrt

Consider this code:

```
double result = Math.Sqrt(4746073226998689451);
```

For result I get 2178548422 instead of 2178548421.999999854etc... How can I get more precise result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the particular problem, computing the square root, you can use Decimal type and Newton's algorithm:

```
using System;

class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    long x = 4746073226998689451;
    decimal sqrt_x = (decimal)Math.Sqrt(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      sqrt_x = 0.5m * (sqrt_x + x / sqrt_x);
    Console.WriteLine("{0:F16}", sqrt_x);
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
2178548421.9999998547197773
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a bunch of high precision maths libraries for .NET mentioned on wikipedia - [Arbitrary-percision artithmatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) page.

I have seen BigNum recommended here before, though the wikipedia link is broken and I can't find the library elsewhere at the moment.

The other option on the page is the [C# binding for MPIR](http://www.alglib.net/x/xmpir).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - So it is. Do you have a link to a working site?

Answer (score 1):

Using [digit by digit calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) will give you as many digits as you are looking for.

Comment: That would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Dykam - Why? I am not suggesting he should code the algorithm himself. If there is an implementation, by all means, use it.

Comment: That's true, but there are many algorithms for arbitrary calculations, this is just one. I think it would've been more useful to link to an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

instead of double , try big integer and also check out this link

[Big numbers with fraction support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533960/big-numbers-with-fraction-support)