# Faster way to divide BigInteger by constant

Tags: c#

i have 2 BigInteger one is constant which is the divisor i use below code to do the division but it takes so long when the dividend is so large . am so confuse coz i do other staff to the dividend even thaw is big but is much faster . Note that the while loop could round 23000K time

i tried to replace / with - but still the while loop will take so long

```
round = 1;

while (MaigicNumber >= divisor) // This may take up to 23000 times coz the Maigic

{ 

    BigInteger jv = BigInteger.Remainder(MaigicNumber, divisor);  
    BigInteger VVJ = jv;

    MaigicNumber = MaigicNumber - jv;
    MaigicNumber = MaigicNumber / divisor;
    PlusArray.Insert(round, VVJ);
    round++;

}
```

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net) says that the compiler has probably already optimized your division procedure and a conversion to bit shifting will probably not be much faster

Comment: did you try to measure which of the lines inside the loop takes actually the most time to perform?

Comment: You could use [BigInteger.DivRem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem?view=netframework-4.8) instead of separate calculations of remainder and division. I.e. `MaigicNumber = BigInteger.DivRem(MaigicNumber, divisor, out VVJ)`

Comment: @MongZhu you mean this is the fastest way the compiler could go to do only division ? but for the same bigInteger i do covert it to binary or * to get it back and it goes 1000 time faster , why only in division it's take so long

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden that does't change match still slow

Comment: Is [this exp/log trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859314/1997232) faster?

Comment: "ou mean this is the fastest way" I don't :) I can only assume that the compiler already optimized it as said in the post. We still don't know whether it is the division that needs the most time.

Comment: I probably don't understand this, but what are you doing exactly? You're saying your implementing division? BigInteger already does division, what am I missing here? My confusion stems from "I use below code to do the division", why not just `MaigicNumber / divisor` ?

Comment: How expensive is PlusArray.Insert() (ie does removing that call speed up the loop significantly)?

Comment: PlusArry is saving the Reminder so i can generate the MaigicNumber again , anyway i don't think this is what slow it  , coz i remove it and still slow

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes i do the division but its very slow when it in the while loop so am trying to find faster way